# Assign labels to Docker daemon

Tags: docker

How do I assign labels to an already running Docker daemon on Ubuntu?

Tried:

```
export DOCKER_OPTS="--label=com.example.storage=ssd"
sudo restart docker
```

but didn't help. `docker info` need to show `Labels`.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Here is the command that worked for me:

sudo sed -i '/#DOCKER_OPTS/c\DOCKER_OPTS="--label=couchbase.mds=index"' /etc/default/docker'

Answer (score 1):

The [docker configuration section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/#/configuring-docker) is clear:

> - Log into your host as a user with sudo or root privileges.
> - If you don’t have one, create the /etc/default/docker file on your host. Depending on how you installed Docker, you may already have this file.
> - Open the file with your favorite editor.

```
    $ sudo vi /etc/default/docker
```

> - Add a `DOCKER_OPTS` variable with the following options. These options are appended to the docker daemon’s run command.

```
    DOCKER_OPTS="--label=com.example.storage=ssd"
```

> - Save and close the file.
> - Restart the docker daemon.

```
    $ sudo restart docker
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i `'/DOCKER_OPTS/c\DOCKER_OPTS="--label=com.example.storage=ssd"' /etc/default/docker`
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess "sudo" isn't copying your environment.  You might try "sudo -E".